# Websphere threads getting exhausted

Tags: java, websphere, thread-dump, websphere-traditional

I have a web application running on websphere, at a certain point of time some web container threads are reported to be hung in IBM WebSphere and later the web container threads are reported to reach its 80% limit .

```
ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread "WebContainer : 7" (00000023) has been active for 758737 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 1 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.
```

later,

`[12/23/16 13:46:14:801 GMT+05:30] 0000048e ThreadPool    I   WSVR0652W: The size of thread pool "WebContainer" has reached 80 percent of its maximum.`

Thread dump did not help me as there are no good sources that tell you how to read threadumps, i can see that some threads are blocked but cant tell on what and why that is happening. Any help deducing is appreciated.Thanks

[Thread dump file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=06369132017628449876)

Comment: You may try to take a couple of threaddumps (say three dumps 10 secs apart) when you first notice the first hung thread message. It tells you the thread name (i.e. "WebContainer : 7") so you can only focus on that thread. In attached dump you already reached an out of memory state (lines below), and it becomes hard to say what's causing what at that point. Try to get the thread dumps early on, and focus on the reported thread.
`1STHEAPTOTAL   Total memory:                  4294967296 
1STHEAPINUSE   Total memory in use:           4285148408 `

Answer (score 1):

you can use Tivoli Performance Viewer to troubleshoot your issue as described in [this resource](http://www.summa.com/blog/2013/12/05/websphere-application-server-performance-tuning-and-troubleshooting). In the same article you'll find  way to tune up your thread pool. Let me also add that the first message that you mention in your question is not necessarily a problem as it just means that one of the thread took too long to answer Nd that could happen physiologically.